# pyspark: Is it possible to add rows to empty dataframe or rdd

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe (created from hive table). I have converted the dataframe to RDD and I am retrieving row by row. On each row, I am parsing every column value and if a particular column is invalid adding to the dictionary with column name and value.

Then I am checking if the dictionary is empty. If non-empty I wanted to add that row to the dataframe. Again continue the same parsing on the next row.

I have created an empty dataframe with the table schema. Is it possible to add the row to the empty dataframe, so that at the end I can save the dataframe to the error_log_table.

Else, please suggest if you have better approach. I was looking at adding a new column to the original dataframe and if the row is invalid, modify that rows' column value to 'T'. By this I can filter the invalid rows. I was not sure how to update the new column value for that particular invalid row alone.

Thank you for your input and suggestion.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `withColumn` function

```
df.withColumn(new_column_name, function_which_will_return_required_value)
```